# Enable Communities with existing Custom Domain

Tags: community, custom-url, custom-domain

I am about to enable Communities in a production org in which customer & partner portals have previously been used with custom URLs through Setup > Domain Management > Domains.  The current custom URL is http://CompanyName.force.com with the path directing the user to the different portals.

Is it possible to use this same custom domain and have the path direct the user to a Community when a community is used and to a Portal when a portal is used?  If so, what do I enter in the domain name input field when enabling Communities?  Because when I do enter the current custom domain, the system errors.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question is "no, not if you continue to maintain another portal or community". If you plan to host more than one community on a domain, you’ll need to set up custom URLs for each site. That's what SF needs in order to uniquely distinguish the communities within your domain. For more, see [Configure a Custom Domain for Your Community](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm) as published in the Summer '14 release notes.